# Data analytics tool for Azure SQL database table

Tags: azure, analytics, visualization

We are a small CRM company. To send campaigns we use MailChimp where we store the lists, create segments etc. One of our clients wants to have access to its list of subscribers on Azure to be able to look, analyse and manipulate with the data in the real time. We have already imported some client’s data to Azure SQL database where we can run some queries in ‘Query editor’. However, it doesn’t work because the client doesn’t know SQL language and client wants to have a simple interface where it is possible to analyse, segment, filter the data, for instance, to see how many subscribers have 1 tag in a specific field in the table, or see the chart with age breakdown of the subscribers. Is there any solution for that data analysis and visualisation? Is that Data Lake Analytics?

Comment: PowerBI has a MailChimp connector in BETA. While I don't know what sort of data volumes you have, this feels like the it might be addressed with a well-designed report.